# How to fill in empty array - invalid syntax

Tags: python, arrays

I have created an empty array which I want to fill.

The array is 10 by 10. I want the first row and column to display text names, which I have in a list of 9. I want the inner 9 by 9 cells to contain another matrix, which I already have filled in with the values.

Here is how I made the matrix and tried to fill in the names so far:

```
rows, cols = (10, 10)
array = [[0 for i in range (cols)] for j in range (rows)]
array [0][1:9] = photographs
array [1:9][0] = photographs
```

where `photographs` is my list of 9 words.

This gives me an array where the first row is as desired, but the first column is still all displaying `0`.

This is what my array looks like:

```
[[0, 'DSC001 \n', 'DSC4587 \n', 'DSC3948 \n', 'DSC98798 \n', 'DSC44 \n', 'DSC098098d \n', 'DSC098734a-796876 \n', 'DSC8976 \n', 'DSC098707-a-b \n', 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I tried to make the cell in the first row and first column display `-` or just a space, but got this error back:

```
    array [0][0] = -
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have also tried to fill in my array with the values from my 9 by 9 matrix like this:

```
array [1:9][1:9] = matrix
```

But this did not work at all.

Comment: `array[0][0] = '-'` ? You are missing the quotes.

Comment: You are working with lists, not arrays. You might be better off working with numpy's arrays as that would allow you to assign to blocks at the same time. But if you work with nested lists, you'll need loops: instead of `array [1:9][0] = photographs` you need `for row in rows: array[row][0] = photographs [row]`

Comment: @Dan thanks for the tip, but I'm a beginner learning and haven't gotten to numpy yet. How can I fill in my second array with my 9 by 9 grid in a similar way to how you suggested with a loop? Do I need to split my 9 by 9 array into lists?

Comment: @Dan also, using the loop you gave, how do I specify to start in the the second column, not the first for the rows, and vice versa for filling in the columns?

Comment: `array[row][1]` for the second column...

Comment: @wilberox you don't have a 9-by-9 array, you have a list containing 9 other lists. So you don't need to split it, but you'll need to loop over the rows.

Comment: @Dan so do I write `for row in rows: array[row][n] = matrix [row][n-1]` but specify earlier that `n=1` and in each iteration through the loop `n=n+1`?

Comment: `for row in rows:
 n = 1
 array[row][n] = matrix [row][n-1]
 n = n+1`  This gives the error  `for row in rows:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nrows = 4
ncols = 4

# Initialize an empty list of lists.
# NB this is a list of lists, not an array. Think of the outer list as a list of rows. Each row is an inner list of 1 element per column.
array = [[0] * ncols for _ in range(ncols)]

# Note that array[n] gets the nth row. array[n][m] gets the element at (n, m).   
# But to get the mth column, you need to do [array[row][m] for row in range(nrows)]. 
# This is reason enough to start thinking about numpy or pandas for an application list this.

headers = ["A", "B", "C"]

# Add the row headers to your 'array'
array[0][1:] = headers
# remember that array[0] gets the first row. It is a list. You can get all the elements except the first by slicing it with [1:]

# Add the column headers to your 'array'
for row_number, row in enumerate(array[1:]):
    row[0] = headers[row_number]
# in this case we need a loop as we want to change the first element of each of the inner lists. A loop over array gives us a row at each iteration. row[0] is then the first column of that row.

# put - in the corner
array[0][0] = "-"

# fill the array with another list

data = [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]
# because both data and array are lists of rows, we do this row by row, skipping the first row
for data_row_number, array_row in enumerate(array[1:]):
    array_row[1:] = data[data_row_number]
```

gives the output for `array` of

```
[['-', 'A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 1, 2, 3], ['B', 4, 5, 6], ['C', 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Filling in the first column should be

```
array[0][1:10] = photographs
```

In python, list slices go from the starting number to one less than the ending number, just like `range`

You can't use `array[1:9][0]` to refer to the first column.
`array[1:9]` is a list containing rows indexed 1 to 8 (so 2nd row to 9th row) so `array[1:9][0]` is just the second row. You could use a for loop to insert the column names instead like:

```
for row in array[1:10]:
    row[0] = photographs[i]
```

Also, to insert a value into the first cell you want:

```
array[0][0] = '-'
```

just like how you would assign a variable.

Comment: `array[0] = photographs[i]
TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: I get this error when I try and do what you said. Is it because I am reading in photographs from a file? If so how can I solve this?

Comment: I get the error `list index out of range` when I try to use `for row in array[1:10]:
    row[0] = photographs[i]`